# Creating and accessing a dynamic array of class objects

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, dynamic

I've been working on a project that deals with phone directories. My program reads data from a datasheet and creates an array of phones.

I have 2 classes : softphone and fleet.

Softphone contains all the values for a phone (private) and get/set and print functions to access them (public).

```
class softphone {

public:
    string name;
    //All my other variables

public:
    softphone();
    softphone(const softphone &obj);
    ~softphone();
    //Get functions
    string get_name();
    //ect
    //Set functions
    void set_name(string);
    //ect
    //Print functions
    void print_name();
    //ect
}
```

Fleet contains the array of phones and output operation function with

```
class fleet {

private:
    //Some variables and buffers

    softphone* phone; ->This is the array containing all the phones 


public:

//Read file and create array functions

//Functions
void print_fleet();
    //More output functions

};
```

The fleet class has a pointer to softphone and I use it to dynamically create an array of phones. It creates the array by reading the directories from a file. ( I don't know how many phone before run time.)

it counts the number of lines in the file and then create and array large enough to hold all the data:

```
phone = new softphone[number_of_lines - 1]; //Line 1 is header
```

It reads from file, saves the data with the set functions, then I increment the pointer using 
    phone++;

So far so good. Now if I want to access these phone and call for a member function.

```
phone[0].print_name();
```

The compiler gives me no error but the output is garbage (Infinite random characters on screen.) I get a std::bad_alloc at memory location exception.

```
for(int i = 0; i < (number_of_lines - 1); i++){
    phone--
}
phone->print_name();
```

Now it works. This way I can access all the phones and print them out fine. All the data is there. But I have to increment/decrement the pointer and I can't work with an index number.

How can i use a index number with this ? And why do the computer go crazy when I use it but is fine when I increment ?

Thanks for the replies,

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Is this going to be another "I can't use `std::vector`" requirement?  If not, `std::vector<softphone> phone;` and ditch the pointers.  Also, your `softphone` class does not need a user-defined copy constructor or destructor -- the compiler default versions will work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the array, phone is pointing to the first element. After that, you start incrementing the pointer until you get to the end of the array. At that point, phone is no longer pointing to the beginning of the array. Then, you run your loop which goes back through the pointers until it gets back to the beginning and things start working again. I recommend that you stop using pointer arithmetic and just use indices. Then, you're assured that phone is always pointing to the beginning of the array. Or, you can assign a different variable and use that for your pointers to fill the array. Or, you can use a std::vector as @PaulMcKenzie suggested.

Comment: Use indices like this ?
phone[0].print_name();

Comment: Yes. But, also when you create the data in the first place, you should just use indices instead of pointer arithmetic. You say you do this: "It reads from file, saves the data with the set functions, then I increment the pointer using phone++;" Instead loop through the phone array, but use phone[i], instead of phone++. Until you are clearer on what incrementing pointers will do, and you know that you need some extra speed in that code, using indices is simpler and clearer. I rarely found myself needing to use pointer arithmetic.

Comment: It compiles but it doesn't work, that the whole point of my question. I get garbage output. But if I increment the pointer and call the same function it works. Thats what i dont understand

Comment: Just remove all places that use phone++ and phone-- and use phone[0], phone[1], phone[i] and everything should work. If it doesn't, post the code.

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much sir !